# Why is this boost::variant example not working?

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting to know boost::variant. I think this example should work.

```
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/sequence.hpp>

#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant/get.hpp>
boost::variant< bool,long,double,std::string,
std::vector<boost::variant<bool> > > v4;
void main()
{

    std::vector<boost::variant<bool> > av (1);
    v4= av;
    try
    {
    bool b=
    boost::get<bool> (v4[0]); // <--- this is line 20
    std::cout << b;


    }
    catch (boost::bad_get v)
    {
    std::cout << "bad get" <<std::endl; 
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error:

d:\m\upp\boosttest\main.cpp(20) : error C2676: binary '[' : 'boost::variant' do
    es not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
        with
        [
            T0_=bool,
            T1=long,
            T2=double,
            T3=std::string,
            T4=std::vector>
        ]

Comment: Why do you use boost::variant<bool>? A single-type variant is kind of useless, no?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`v4[0]` is not valid since v4 is a variant, not a vector. You need to use `boost::get` to retrieve the vector stored in it first. So, line 20 should be

`boost::get<bool>(boost::get<std::vector<boost::variant<bool> > >(v4)[0]);`

Comment: A typedef for `std::vector<boost::variant<bool> >` helps a little. Not using variants of vectors of variants helps more :)

Comment: topic-starter, i suggest you to use typedefs.
and, excuse me for my notes, but it's better to catch exceptions by const reference, i.e. try{/**/} catch (const boost::bad_get &v){ /**/}

Comment: @varnie or at least by non-const reference.

Comment: What difference does it meake if I use reference or not?

Comment: If you're catching a base class exception, like std::exception, then you won't get the same error reporting from derived exceptions. I think it's called slicing? But with a reference the exception won't be copied (wrongly) and it will retain the derived class' properties.